# Python3 csv DictWriter: writing through bz2 fails (TypeError: 'str'/buffer interface)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am trying to write an on-the-fly bz2-compressed csv file in python3.

Without compression this works fine:

```
from csv import DictWriter

FIELDNAMES = ('a', 'b')
OUT_CSV = 'out.csv'

DATA = ({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a':3, 'b':4})

# works fine
with open(OUT_CSV, 'w') as file_pointer:
    csv_writer = DictWriter(file_pointer, fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for dataset in DATA:
        csv_writer.writerow(dataset)
```

Adding compression it fails:

```
from csv import DictWriter
import bz2

FIELDNAMES = ('a', 'b')
OUT_BZ2 = 'out.csv.bz2'

DATA = ({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a':3, 'b':4})

# this fails
with bz2.open(OUT_BZ2, mode='w', compresslevel=9) as file_pointer:
    csv_writer = DictWriter(file_pointer, fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
    csv_writer.writeheader() # fails here; raises "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"
    for dataset in DATA:
        csv_writer.writerow(dataset)
```

with the Exception: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

Is there a buffer-compatible csv module out there? Or do I have to write the csv rows by hand? or is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `bz2.open` defaults to binary mode.  This is in contrast to the regular Python built-in `open` which defaults to text mode.  To solve your error, you simply need to open the file in text mode, not the default binary mode.  Change the `with bz2.open(... mode='w'...)` to `with bz2.open(... mode='wt'...)`.  I tested on Python 3.4.

Comment: You might want to point out that this is a difference between `bz2.open` and the builtin `open` function. The former defaults to binary mode, while the later defaults to text mode.

Comment: thank you @Blckknght. That is an excellent point. I will update my answer accordingly.  Kudos!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, Very glad to help!